# When a title is used as a common noun, should it be capitalised?

Tags: nouns, capitalization, titles

In the company I work for, we have a process called an Engineering Request, the document produced as a result of following the process is also referred to as an Engineering Request. Typically, it's written in its capitalised form as it's the title of a process (and document).

My question is, when the term is used as a common noun, for example, "We will provide you with all the relevant Engineering Request documents", is it correct to capitalise it? It just doesn't quite feel right when the term is used as a common noun, and as such, I tend not to capitalise it, but when my documents are reviewed, the reviewer tends to capitalise them before sending them out to customers.

Comment: If you're referring to documents produced by the process you describe, retain the capitals to reinforce this, especially for the benefit of outsiders. I'd interpret _engineering request_ as a request for some engineering to be done by some unspecified party.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, yes, that's exactly how I'm referring to it, but if the term Engineering Request in this instance refers to the abstract noun version of the document that doesn't yet exist, doesn't that make it a common noun?

Comment: Proper nouns are used to give prominence to important (perhaps only to some!) examples of things / concepts. Think of the 'Great Leap Forward' as opposed to say a great leap forward in cancer treatment. 'The Next Big Thing'.